# Getting access token for paypal rest api grails

Tags: grails, curl, paypal, oauth, httpclient

How can I use paypal rest api in grails

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

DOC : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

I need to get the authentication token in grails. It's working in terminal without any problem.

I'm trying to use `HttpClient` for implementing that, but how to pass the user credentials . Specified in the above example with `-u uname:pass` in `HttpClient`.?

Comment: is there a reason not to use the official java rest-api-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using **Basic Auth** to authenticate (see [how to set basic auth in curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#Basic_Authentication) and [the client's section for Basic Auth in the Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side).

Apache's Http Client offers authentication handling for you, but in this case it seems easier to just create the header manually:

```
Request addBasicAuthHeader(String username, String password) {
   return addBasicAuthHeader(createBasicAuth(username, password))
}

Request addBasicAuthHeader(String headerValue) {
   request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic ${headerValue}")
   return request
}

private String createBasicAuthHeader(String username, password) {
   "$username:$password".toString().bytes.encodeBase64()
}
```

You can invoke any of the `addBasicAuthHeader` methods (maybe adapting them to the flavour of `HttpClient` you are using), allowing you to add the basic auth header from its raw value (what you have in `curl`'s `-u` flag) or from a pair of username and password.

Comment: I added a couple of links to illustrate my assumptions and how the basic auth header is calculated. I am not sure of how to ellaborate more, specially without any code from your side to comment to.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response , I will try your code :)